# What hardware acceleration functions does common processors have

Tags: linux, gpu, cpu, hardware-acceleration

I've been searching for hardware acceleration explanations and I came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12355944/16990740) .

It says that hardware acceleration is "when you have hardware designed to accelerate a specific function". Okay, got it.

Now, I would like to know what kind of functions are these. I can think of a function for disk cryptography.

Could you please provide me with some Intel or AMD documentation that tells what are these functions?
.
PS: We are speaking of common computer processors, like i3 i5 i7 i9.

I've tried to search online for the documentation or functions that hardware accelerations are made for.
I am expecting some examples of hardware accelerations functions and explanation of what they are used for.

Comment: AES-NI or SHA-NI are good examples (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aesenc / https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sha1rnds4), also carryless multiply (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pclmulqdq).  And the newer Galois-field instructions like https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/gf2p8affineqb.  Older SIMD instructions that help with specific things in video encoding include [`psadbw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psadbw) sum of absolute differences in 8-byte chunks for motion-search and other similarity checks.  Also fixed-point mul + right shift https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmulhrsw

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set

Comment: Lots of specialized hardware accelerates 3D rendering for video games. If it wasn't for that, you probably wouldn't have a GPU at all. Other examples include  MMX, 3DNow!, Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE) and Advanced Vector Extensions (AVX).